# Is it possible to use MongoDB Views with Azure CosmosDB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi, database-view

I tried to create a view via Robo3T. The command executes successfully, but the view is always empty, no matter how I specify the aggregation pipeline for the view. 
Example:

```
db.createView("testView","originCollection", [{
    $project : {
        _id: 1
    } 
}])
```

Does CosmosDB even support views for MongoDB?

---

Edit: As Kevin Smith asked in comments `db.testView.stats()` returns:

```
{
    "_t" : "CollStatsResponse",
    "ok" : 1,
    "ns" : "myDb.testView",
    "count" : 0.0,
    "size" : 0,
    "avgObjSize" : 0,
    "numExtents" : 0,
    "lastExtentSize" : 0,
    "paddingFactor" : 0,
    "systemFlags" : 0,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 0,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "indexSizes" : {}
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you get if you run a `db.testView.stats()`?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I added the output to the original question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the details that you have given, it looks like it's treating the view as just another collection and nothing is happening when you create a view (I've seen this with other commands it just continues without any errors).

When you call stats on a view you'd normally end up with the following

```
db.testView.stats()
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Namespace test.testView is a view, not a collection",
    "code" : 166,
    "codeName" : "CommandNotSupportedOnView"
}
```

Also, looking at the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support#administration-commands) the Administration Commands don't support `createView`.