# DB Views in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: database, mongodb, azure, view, azure-cosmosdb

We are planning to use Azure Cosmos as a DB for Storing a bunch of Documents (JSON Objects), Does Cosmos have any feature to create Views like [Mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/)

I searched many places but could not get details

Comment: Getting there: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/announcing-materialized-view-feature-for-azure-cosmos-db-nosql-preview/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/) and [Administration Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support#administration-commands), the feature is not supported by cosmos db mongo api yet.(Please see a similar thread:[Is it possible to use MongoDB Views with Azure CosmosDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55060005/is-it-possible-to-use-mongodb-views-with-azure-cosmosdb))

Per my knowledge, CosmosDB just supports a subset of the MongoDB API. CosmosDB has some different behaviours and results. But the onus is on CosmosDB to improve their emulation of MongoDB.

In addition, you could add [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) here to submit your requirements.Or you could consider using [MongoDB Atlas](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/microsoft-azure/) on Azure if you'd like full MongoDB feature support.

Comment: Our Enterprise only supports Cosmos, so we are little bit contrained

Comment: @Sandeep540 Fine,you may could submit feedback  to azure cosmos team to push the improvement of this feature you want.

Comment: Sure, will do it

Comment: @Sandeep540 Any updates you could share here,Thanks.